Is there any way to view output from an Xcode scheme's build pre-action / verify it completed successfully?
I've got a custom run script build phase in my Xcode iOS project, however I want it to run before the items in the Target Dependencies section get built.
So I added a Pre-Actions phase to the target's build scheme and pasted the contents there.
However, during a build, there's no way to see if the stuff in the pre action is successful or not. It's possible to put echo statements into a run script build phase which is useful to print values such as file paths etc. but these don't work when part of a scheme pre action.
Also if I deliberately put garbage into the scheme pre action, then I can see Xcode is still running the pre action, but as its full of garbage it should fail, but Xcode doesn't report any errors anywhere.
So, is there any way to see and confirm if a scheme pre-action was successful or not, or to output logging statements from it to verify values its using are as expected?
